# How to load ENV variable to Typescript Yaml File

Tags: typescript, yaml

I was trying to run a sample project, where it does not specify clearly where to define variables and load it correspondingly.

Here's the serverless.yml

```js
service: nft-marketplace

custom:
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js
    includeModules: true
  serverless-offline:
    httpPort: 4000
  customDomain:
    apiType: rest
    autoDomain: true
    basePath: ${self:provider.stage}
    createRoute53Record: true
    certificateArn: ${env:CERTIFICATE_ARN }
    domainName: ${env:DOMAIN_NAME }
    endpointType: 'edge'
    hostedZoneId:  ${env:ZONE_ID }
    securityPolicy: tls_1_2
```

Then I define the variable in .env file in the Typescript project like below,

```js
DOMAIN_NAME: localhost
CERTIFICATE_ARN: sample
ZONE_ID: sample
```

When I run npm start, it shows the following error:

```js
Environment: darwin, node 16.11.1, framework 3.14.0, plugin 6.2.1, SDK 4.3.2
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
  - Cannot resolve variable at "custom.customDomain.certificateArn": Value not found at "env" source,
  - Cannot resolve variable at "custom.customDomain.domainName": Value not found at "env" source,
  - Cannot resolve variable at "custom.customDomain.hostedZoneId": Value not found at "env" source,
```

Can anyone help here?

Comment: This guide on serverless env configuration looks comprehensive, however, it still cannot resolve the errors, https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-dotenv-plugin

Comment: As far as I know serverless-dotenv is not compatible with new version of serverless, maybe try degrading or using the default useDotEnv option from serverless.
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/environment-variables